# I'd like to delete the top (header) row from a list of multiple tables

Tags: r

I read in multiple .csv files from a directory using list.files(path, pattern=".csv"), then lapply(data, read.csv) which opens them as a list of tables in R. The headers are attached (like they're part of the data) & I'd like to delete the first row from each table in the list to eliminate them & make my own headers.
I was able to do this when I read in 1 file at a time using lapply(data[-1,]) but now it's not working on the list of tables..
Do I have to turn them into a data frame first?
If so I'm not sure how to go about this in a data frame..?
Thx in advance

Comment: does `lapply(data, read.csv, skip = 1)` work?

Comment: That attached an x. before each 'cell' of data in the first row.. x.value x.value..

Comment: `lapply(data, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE)`

Comment: Thx rawr! lapply(data, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE)Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to change the header of the files in your directory, then attach them together:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  dataset <- fread(x,header=TRUE, sep=",")
  setnames(dataset,c("Name1","Name2"))
  return(dataset)
}

data <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(),myfun))
```